# Is it possible to have compatibility issues with old GPU and new motherboards?

Tags: graphics-card, bios, motherboard, gpu

I have a fairly old graphics card (Nvidia GTX 660 OEM) that I pulled from an Alienware gaming computer that I am trying to use in another computer. I am running into strange issues with the graphics card such as everything freezing except the mouse. A particularly peculiar issue is the fact that the BIOS screen sometimes takes forever to show up and the graphics card is stuck on a black screen with a flashing cursor on the top left. This happens before the OS is even loaded so it has led me to suspect the issue is hardware related (although I am not familiar with the low level details of the boot process but I am basing this off experience that my boot usually goes something like: black screen w/ blinking cursor on top left -> BIOS screen -> splashscreen for OS). So far, I have been able to test the GPU on the Alienware and another similarly old (all circa 2012-2013) machine and it seems to work just fine.

Given that the [GPU uses PCIe 3.0](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/graphics-cards/geforce-gtx-660/specifications/) and the motherboard ([ASRock z490M-ITX/ac](https://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/Z490M-ITXac/index.asp)) also supports PCIE 3.0 could there be other potential issues in compatibility here?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu, but this issue happens before it even starts booting

Comment: What happened that forces you to change GPU?

Comment: Wouldn't a conflict between your processor's built-in GPU and the NVidia be more probable?

Comment: It should be compatible without a problem. Have you been able to test a different card with this build? It might be worth resetting the bios to its defaults and have a look at the PCI-E settings to see if anything is obviously wrong. I'm presuming that you have at least a 450w psu and that you've connected the 6 pin connector on the top of the card?

Comment: If your old GPU was fried, there is a chance for more damage.

Comment: Yes so this black screen problem happens 75% of the time. The GPU runs fine on 2 other computers with motherboards from around the same time (2012). And yes, I have a 600w PSU and have plugged in the PCIe power supply.

Comment: I wasn’t forced to change GPU, this is a new build and I am temporarily using an old GPU from an old computer due to the shortage in GPU availability in the current market.